# How to change a property on an object without mutating it?

Tags: javascript

```
const a = {x: "Hi", y: "Test"}
const b = ???
// b = {x: "Bye", y: "Test"}
// a = {x: "Hi", y: "Test"}
```

How can I set `b.x` to `"Bye"` without mutating a?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Two ways...

1. You can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

   ```js
   const a = { x: "Hi", y: "Test" }
   const b = Object.assign({}, a, { x: "Bye" });
   console.log("a:", a);
   console.log("b:", b);
   console.log("a === b:", a === b);
   ```
2. Or you can use the [object spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals).

   The spread operator allows you to "assign" all properties of one object to another.

   We can use it here within an object literal to assign all properties of `a` to `b`:

   ```js
   const additions = { x: "Bye" }
   const a = { x: "Hi", y: "Test" }
   const b = { ...a,  ...additions } // or { ...a, x: "Bye" }
   console.log("a:", a);
   console.log("b:", b);
   console.log("a === b:", a === b);
   ```

Comment: Actually the spread operator desugars down to Object.assign so its not so much as an alternative, both are equivalent. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread/blob/master/Spread.md

Comment: I'm pretty sure Object.assign mutates the target object. In this case "a" would not be mutated, but "b" would be a mutated object. Mutation causes new Hidden Classes to be created (at least in V8) which can decrease performance. I'm not sure if spread has the same issue.

Answer (score 39):

there's an easy way to change object property without mutating the original object.

```js
const a = {x: "Hi", y: "Test"};
const b = {...a, y: "hello"};
```

Comment: Note: **The spread operator makes deep copies of data if the data is not nested only** otherwise it does a shallow copy of the original object in this case the original object can still be mutated.

Answer (score 13):

Create a copy of the object and change the copy:

```
const b = Object.assign({}, a, {x: "Bye"})
```

---

[Docs for `Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 1):

Es6 has a built in function for copying object properties, `Object.assign`

```
const b = Object.assign({}, a, {x: 'Bye'})
```

here we create an empty object, push all of `a`s key value pairs in, followed by the new key value pairs we want to over write. because the empty object is the first argument, we mutate that object, not `a`

Answer (score -1):

Try this : `const b = a.map(item => Object.assign({}, ...item));` This will create a new object without any reference to the old object `a`

In case if you want to do this for an array try the same with `[]`

```
const b = a.map(item => Object.assign([], ...item));
```

Comment: Pretty sure map is only an array method