# Eslint rule "no-param-reassign" how to fix the warning in my case

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I learn JavaScript React and came across this [Eslint warning](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) and don't know how to fix it properly

The code works but the warning is here on the image:

[image]

Code piece:

```
const FilePicker = ({ setNewFileForValidation }) => {
    const readFileContents = async file => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = () => {
                resolve(fileReader.result);
            };
            fileReader.onerror = reject;
            fileReader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        });
    };
    const readAllFiles = async AllFiles => {
        const results = await Promise.all(
            AllFiles.map(async file => {
                const fileContents = await readFileContents(file);
                file.md5 = SHA256(fileContents).toString();
                return file;
            }),
        );
        console.log(results, 'resutls');
        return results;
    };

    function onDrop(acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
        readAllFiles(acceptedFiles).then(result => {
            setNewFileForValidation(result);
        });
    }
    return <Dropzone onDrop={onDrop} />;
};
```

I can't see how I can *not* use the `file`, adding to it during every iteration.

Comment: How to fix any ESLint problem: 1. Read the rule description (here: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) 2. fix the code or disable the rule.

Comment: @VLAZ so you mean some things cant be fixed so one must disable the rule?

Comment: I mean that most rules are mostly stylistic in nature and not objectively right or wrong. So, you might want to ignore them in some cases. In this case, it's completely unclear what you want to do because we have no idea *why* the rule was enabled. Do you really want no mutation ever? Then you'd need to change your `.map()` callback to not mutate its input. Do you actually *want* to mutate the input? Then you need to disable the rule. Do you not care about it either way? Then: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. Combined altogether the answer is still ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ to pretty much anybody that's not you.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the insightful comment, but how can I insert the SHA256 like - `file.md5 = SHA256(fileContents).toString();` without mutate of the `file`

Comment: `return file;` -> `return { ...file, md5: SHA256(fileContents).toString() };` clone the object and override the `md5` property. [How to change a property on an object without mutating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37932434)

Comment: @VLAZ oh yea that was perfect I learn so much now. Create and Answer maybe?

Comment: @VLAZ Using the `return { ...file, md5: SHA256(fileContents).toString() };`, will only clone [one](https://snipboard.io/bcLtfD.jpg) of the existing key-value pares in `file`, there are like 7. But I read this is suppose to work like this but not, any ide? [Here's result](https://snipboard.io/hve32f.jpg)

Comment: Then the question is - what is `file`? Apparently, it's not a plain object. From the output, I'd assume the rest of the properties come from the prototype or something. You should probably clone with the prototype intact.